# How to render custom components vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, rendering

```
<div v-for="item in inputState.allInputFields" :key="item.inputtype">
    <!-- <el-form-item label="{{ item.name[0].toUpperCase() + selectName.value.slice(1) }}" prop="{{ item.name }}"> -->
    <RenderString :input-html="item.inputtype" />
    <!-- </el-form-item> -->
  </div>
```

here is renderComponent

```
<script>
import { h } from 'vue'
export default {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    inputHtml: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  render() {
    const tag = this.inputHtml.split('v-')[0].replace('<', '').trim()
    const vModel = `equipment.${this.inputHtml.split('.')[1].split('" ')[0]}`.trim()
    console.log(tag, vModel)
    return h(tag, {
      modelValue: vModel,
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

these are my logs

```
el-switch equipment.active RenderInputs.vue:14:13
el-input equipment.description RenderInputs.vue:14:13
el-input equipment.division RenderInputs.vue:14:13
el-input equipment.modifiedBy RenderInputs.vue:14:13
```

i have a reactive list with html from these element ui input components and i want them to dynamically be added and removed to this equipment object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3xlb.png)

Comment: You don't need to form vModel string, you already have access to equipment.active, etc values in render function. See vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-model  . This looks like XY problem because parsing inputHtml is not practical.

Comment: what is xy problem, how can i display this inputfield ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . You're addressing potentially wrong solution. Consider reasking the question with the whole relevant info. You may want to reconsider the way you store data about form comps. You preferably should keep it not as fake html but the way it can be easily rendered as dynamic comp, like <component :is="item.compName" v-bind="item.compProps">